# Copy/Move Item api is not throwing exception when i provide invalid parentReference.id with in drive

Tags: copy, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

Both Move and copy apis are successful when we provide invalid ParentReference.id with in drive. And it is copying the file to same folder as source item. Expected Behaviour : It should throw invalid parentReferece.id error. This functionality is working fine when we provide invalid parentReference.path.

Copy Item : POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!dckkz8p7EkKltFwLt5o0QJ6VxtVc1UlOlv0XvR1bhLAo3oh17BLfTIZmGKhBkrry/root:/home/new-item.jpg:/microsoft.graph.copy

{'name':'test5.jpg','parentReference':{'driveId':'b!dckkz8p7EkKltFwLt5o0QJ6VxtVc1UlOlv0XvR1bhLAo3oh17BLfTIZmGKhBkrry','id':'fgdftgarsgdreg'}}

Move Item : PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!dckkz8p7EkKltFwLt5o0QJ6VxtVc1UlOlv0XvR1bhLAo3oh17BLfTIZmGKhBkrry/root:/home/new-item.jpg:

{'name':'test6.jpg','parentReference':{'id':'fgdftgarsgdreg'}}

Comment: Can you repro the issue consistently?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity yes, I am still looking for the help. I could able to reproduce the issue consistently. I have added my latest  request details here in github(https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1381). Do let me know, if you have any workaround for this.

Comment: Looks like its working for me. Can you test the same?